# cat <<-EOTT > on scripts

Tags: shell, unix

Can some one explain what that line does, Ive seen it in other places also as:
cat <<'EOTT' > filename
I would like to find a unix or shell education site that explains what EOTT is and if there are other Acronyms (call it like that until I know what it really is)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an example of a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).  It's a way of piping lines of input contained within a shell script into a program (`cat` in the above case).

"EOTT" is the *limit string* of the here document - it marks where the here document ends.  It doesn't necessarily need to stand for anything (indeed, random nonsense limit strings are common for here documents in programmatically-generated shell scripts).

Answer (score 1):

This is a ["here document"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) notation, where you specify a tag up until which you would read your text. If you want to feed multi-line input to your command, you can do it like this:

```
mycommand <<MYFANCYTAG
...
 many lines of input
...
MYFANCYTAG
```

It is a neat way to provide multi-line input without creating an extra input file.